# Return last used row in a named range as Long

Tags: excel, vba, range, long-integer

I am having great difficulty defining my `Long` ("Last") as the last used row number in the `Range` "SortRng". Any help please? It doesn't like

```
Last = SortRng.End(xlDown).Resize(, .Columns.Count).Row
```

The code is attempting to delete the entire row if there is no value in "E", "I" & "M"

```
For Each thisCellInGame In GameRng
    If thisCellInGame.Value = "Game On!" Then
            Set SortRng = thisCellInGame.Offset(2, 3).Resize(26, 2)
            With SortRng
            Last = SortRng.End(xlDown).Resize(, .Columns.Count).Row
            End With
            first = Last - 25
                For i = Last To First Step -1
                    If (Cells(i, "E").Value) = "" And (Cells(i, "I").Value) = "" And (Cells(i, "M").Value) = "" Then
                        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next i
            End
    End If
Next thisCellInGame
End
```

Comment: `Last = SortRng.Row + SortRng.Rows.Count - 1`

Comment: Similarly, `Last = SortRng.Offset(SortRng.Rows.Count - 1).Row`.

Comment: This code looks highly unusual. `SortRng` looks pretty useless. Could you share an example of the `GameRng.Address` (e.g. `A1:A100`) so someone could suggest a better approach?